# My text boxes appear prolonged to the right of the screen as "ghosts". How to fix this?

Tags: windows, display

It's just a visual bug, but it's extremely annoying with menus with lots of items or simple graphic programs like Minecraft. On more advanced graphics it's hardly observable.

**I couldn't provide any screenshots because the issue didn't render when opened on another device, meaning that the problem is related to the monitor itself.**

I searched in the monitor's options, but I didn't find anything that was related to this. **Do you have any idea on how to fix this?**

Comment: Have you tried a new monitor cable? See [How to Fix LCD Monitor Ghost Images](http://www.madebymark.com/2009/02/25/2009225how-to-fix-lcd-monitor-ghost-images-html/)

Comment: is this an old CRT monitor, or a "flatscreen"? Are you using VGA to connect, or some digital interface? If you're using VGA, depending on how the cable is positioned, interference can be getting into the cable and causing that exact effect.

Comment: @Blaine It's an LCD Widescreen.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'll try that; the monitor cable did do some other problems in the past.

Comment: I just moved the cable a little in its slot and it got fixed. Thanks for your help. @DavidPostill

Comment: @John Great. I will post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Text boxes appear prolonged to the right of the screen as "ghosts"

This can be caused by a defective monitor cable. In your case by not having the cable plugged in correctly it's shielding was compromised.

> On what has always been a perfectly good LCD monitor, you begin to see a faint but distracting “ghost image” to the left or right of desktop elements (like windows, icons, or black text on a white screen). Unlike the burned-in images associated with old CRT or new plasma monitors, this image is “live” — when you move screen elements or change the contents of the screen, the ghost image moves and changes, too. The effect looks a bit like those slightly-offset ghost images you used to see on television screens back when t.v.’s were hooked up to “rabbit ears.”
>
> In most cases, it’s the monitor cable. If this just started, you probably added some new electronic gizmo to your desktop, or the shielding on your current monitor cable has been compromised in some way. If the monitor cable is touching another cable, a modem, or even an inkjet printer, move the cable. If this doesn’t fix the problem, replace the monitor cable.

Source [How to Fix LCD Monitor Ghost Images](http://www.madebymark.com/2009/02/25/2009225how-to-fix-lcd-monitor-ghost-images-html/)